# How to enable navigation click only after a http call has been made?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation

I have a problem in my Android app.

I have a bottom navigation menu for navigating through fragments of MainActivity.
Problem is that on 3 of those fragments, I am making a http call that retrieves the data for those fragments.
If I click a navigation item too soon, and another fragment loads before the http is resolved, my application crashes because it tries to load the data into view items that no longer exist.

My question is, how can I disable bottom navigation untill the http request loads the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your activity could start with the menu items disabled so the user knows that the app is not prepared to navigate there.

```java
    bottomBar.menu.findItem(R.id.frag1).isEnabled = false
    ..... // same for every item
```

And on your http call there should be some method like `onResponse()` (Retrofit) or anything like that where you can enable them.

```java
    public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) { 
         if(response.isSuccessful()){
             bottomBar.menu.findItem(R.id.frag1).isEnabled = true;
             ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yesss, it is simple and it works!

Thanks!